# ios app crash on start after splashscreen

Tags: ios

```
**LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and is required for iOS 9.0
2022-05-10 14:56:48.547892+0500 PohodlnýOnline Nákupy[48489:3393895] [native] Unable to find module for AccessibilityManager
2022-05-10 14:56:48.567291+0500 PohodlnýOnline Nákupy[48489:3394150] -[RCTCxxBridge devSettings]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13ff14620
2022-05-10 14:56:48.568291+0500 PohodlnýOnline Nákupy[48489:3394150] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RCTCxxBridge devSettings]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13ff14620'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18120b70c 0x198946f04 0x1812dc230 0x1811a4ffc 0x1811a420c 0x102eb4730 0x102eaeb04 0x1044b86fc 0x1044b9fc4 0x1044cc01c 0x1044cc84c 0x1dc267dd4 0x1dc26793c)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
dyld4 config: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RCTCxxBridge devSettings]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13ff14620'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**strong text****
```

getting this error while build app from xcode

Comment: What is accessibility manager ?

Comment: don't know ....

Comment: Thread 1: "*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]"

now this error is showing..

Comment: set a breakpoint in your app to pause on the line where the crash is occurring: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/xcode/how-to-create-exception-breakpoints-in-xcode

Comment: crash is occur in main.m ios file opn this line 'UIApplicationMain'

    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

Comment: What the definition of AppDelagate class ? Did you changed you Appdelegate class name ?

Comment: no my appdelegate class name are Appdelegate.m and Appdelegate.h

Comment: Are you handling some URL schemes in your App ?

Comment: <array>
  <dict>
   <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
   <array>
    <string>fb818255692052696</string>
   </array>
  </dict>
 </array>